# How to repair a mat with a hole in it?

Tags: equipment

So, there was an incident and now one of the mats has a hole in it.  The hole is about 1 x 0.5 cm wide.  What is the best way to repair it so it is still safe to train on said mat?

The mat is a plastic covered foamed judo mat similar to [this one](http://www.blitzsport.com/IJF-Competition-Judo-Mat?sc=8&category=6544).

Comment: Is the mat made of vinyl, canvas, covered foam, uncovered foam, shredded tires, is it a puzzle mat, is it a superconductor...? Details about the situation allow for better answers.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann: Question edited.

Comment: I believe there are kits that have like a caulking compound and a vinyl latex that you can paint over the top of it.

http://www.resilite.com/Departments/Wrestling-Mats-and-Supplies/Mat-Care-and-Cleaning/Mat-Repair-Supplies.aspx

http://swainmats.com/store/store/comersus_listItems.asp?idCategory=31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a huge hole. I would at least consider taping it and moving it to the to a spot off to the side.

If that solution sets off your safety or insurance alarms, I'd look into a [mat repair kit](http://swainmats.com/store/store/comersus_viewItem.asp?idProduct=218). The Swain one includes:

> - (1) 7/8" x 7/8" patch
> - (1) 1 3/8" x 1 3/8" patch
> - (1) 36" reinforcement filament for repairing tears at edges
> - (2) Alcohol Prep pads
> - Set of illustrated instructions

Wrestling mats have a different set of [recommended patch kits](http://www.resilite.com/Departments/Wrestling-Mats-and-Supplies/Mat-Care-and-Cleaning/Mat-Repair-Supplies.aspx).